# Как проверить строку, является ли она директорией, если ее не существует в системе?

Tags: java, файлы

Собственно сабж: есть директория, которую вводит юзер, но она может не существовать в системе (соотвествено если она не существует, я ее создаю). File.isDirectory возвращает true, только если эта директория существует. Как еще можно проверить?

Comment: интересно, за что минус поставили? Неплохой вопрос вроде

Comment: когда дадут верный ответ, или приближенный хотя бы, я обязательно отмечу его как верный.На данный момент верного ответа мне не дали =)

Comment: Я бы конвертировал в file url и проверял валидность урла. Первая же страница гугла богато играет ответами, но я ни один из них не пользовал, вот пара оптимистичных - url-валидатор http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java и просто типичный URL http://stackoverflow.com/a/5719282

Comment: @Etki, а что там вооьще, например для \*nix-вых файловых систем, можно проверить?

Только то, что расстояние между соседними слешами не больше 255 байт?

Comment: @avp, а вопрос поставлен в контексте никсовых систем?

Comment: @Etki, любых. Между прочим, вполне возможен вариант, когда правила меняются где-то в середине пути (символьный линк на точку монтирования с файловой системой другого типа).

Все эти слова к тому, что подобные проверки **бесполезны**. 

Достоверный ответ может дать только ОС и только в момент создания (или этого оглавления или его содержимого).

--

Т.е. на самом деле вместо предварительной проверки надо правильно запрограммировать обработку ошибок при занесении информации в заданное пользователем оглавление  
(выяснили в процессе обмена комментариями с @VladD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Так нельзя проверить является ли строка директорией. Это проверка на существование, если не существует он вернет fakse. А как мне проверить что директория например /home/user/somedir/ является путем, даже если этой директории у меня нет на компе ?
```

Никак. Т.к. до момента создания файла/директории НЕИЗВЕСТНО, кто это на самом деле будет. Попробуй создать файл без расширения в одной папке и такую же директорию рядом с файлом. По крайней мере в NTFS это невозможно. Отсюда вывод: до того как создан файл/директория, ты не узнаешь, кто это на самом деле.

Comment: Ну вот такой ответ я в принципе и ожидал, спасибо =)

Answer (score 4):

Можно вот так:

```
File f = new File(path);
if(f.exists()) {

}
```

Работает как для файла, так и для директории.

Comment: Так нельзя проверить является ли строка директорией. Это проверка на существование, если не существует он вернет fakse. А как мне проверить, что директория, например, `/home/user/somedir/`, является путем, даже если этой директории у меня нет на компе?

Comment: Если бы речь шла о \*nix и не о Java, то проще всего просто попробовать создать (mkdir) и проверить код возврата.

Но это ведь Java... Ее (в таком виде) большие умники придумали.

Comment: тогда остается один выход,это старые добрые регулярки.... =)

Comment: >попробовать создать (mkdir) и проверить код возврата

@avp имхо это очень плохой способ, хоть и самый простой

Comment: @DreamChild, обосновать сможете?

Comment: @avp: Например, если файловая система находится на backup-ленте в Австралии, это может запустить процесс распаковки каталога из backup'а.

А ещё файловая система может быть смонтирована как read-only. А ещё у вас может не быть прав на доступ. А ещё каталог может быть в каком-нибудь системном месте наподобие `/proc`.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/05/9903476.aspx

Comment: @VladD, в данном случае этого все равно не избежать, из-за слов ТС:

    соотвествено если она не существует, я ее создаю

Вот я и пишу -- просто создай, но проверь результат, намекая, что try/catch требует ввода большего числа буковок для этого.

Comment: @avp: Если создаёт — тогда проверка вовсе не нужна. Т. к. немедленно после проверки её результат не имеет смысла — из другого процесса родительский каталог могут удалить, на месте вашего каталога могут создать файл и т. п.

Я обеими руками я try/catch.

Comment: Лимит-с...  Пришлось удалять и вставлять.

@VladD, а это здравая мысль (не проверять, т.е. при создании каталога пустой catch).

@DreamChild, еще раз -- ТС пишет "соотвествено если она не существует, я ее создаю".

А Вы рассматриваете какой-то другой случай. Причем, без реальных обращений к файловой системе (stat()) с целью проверки существования промежуточных каталогов, Ваш метод слишком формальный. 

Теперь по поводу накладных расходов. Разница между однократным mkdir при условии, что оглавление существует и несколькими stat (для компонент пути), будет в пользу одного mkdir.

--

Все, limit

Comment: @avp, да, я не обратил внимание на важное замечание "соотвествено если она не существует, я ее создаю". Однако и в этом случае ваш метод не хорош - он не гибок и содержит побочные эффекты (а они - зло само по себе по вполне понятным причинам). Сейчас ТС хочет делать именно так (если не существует - создаю), а потом захочет сделать иначе, и создание папки окажется ненужным (да, вы можете возразить, что, дескать сейчас он хочет именно так, а не иначе, но не мне вам рассказывать, что  поскольку требования к ПО меняются регулярно, должно быть гибким и расширяемым, а костыли - зло)